# How to pass another parameter to extended userStore class using Identity in dotnet core

Tags: c#, .net-core, identity

I'm implementing a simple Multi-Tenant app and for that, I have extended the `UserStore` class this way:

```
public class ApplicationUserStore : UserStore<OmniUser>
{
    public string TenantId { get; set; }

    public ApplicationUserStore(OmniDbContext context, IdentityErrorDescriber describer = null)
        : base(context, describer) { }

    // overrided methods
}
```

To configure dependency injection to use the extended `UserStore` I added this code to the Startup ConficureServices method:

```
services.AddIdentity<OmniUser, IdentityRole>()
 .AddEntityFrameworkStores<OmniDbContext>()
 .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
 .AddUserStore<ApplicationUserStore>(); // Extended UserStore
```

I can see the service is correctly instantiated and that the overrided methods are working well on `ApplicationUserStore`.

The problem is I need to pass the `TenantId` to my `UserStore`. I know that I can create another constructor that accepts an additional variable but then I don't know how to instantiate it using DI.

I could create a shortcut and define it manually through the `UserManager` class but it seems I don't have access to the `UserStore` from the `UserManager` instance.

How can I do this in an elegant way? I'm trying to avoid to instantiate both my custom `UserStore` and `UserManager` manually.

Thank you.

Comment: Passing a subclass property to a superclass is probably bad idea breaking OOP principles. Do you have access to `UserStore` code and how do you plan to use `TenandId` there? Why don't you just declare and instantiate `TenantId` at `UserStore`?

Comment: Hi, thank you. Tenant id is used there because I'm changing the implementation of CreateUser method and others. The changes will allow to have the same username and or email registered in more than one tenant. My idea is to pass the TenantId and then check if there is or if I can create a user associated with that specific Tenant. The ApplicationUser also have the corresponding TenantId